# Not able to create project in Angular 7?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, angular7

I have faced an issue when I have created new project using "ng new MyTestApp".

It returned **"Access is denied"**

*Attached Screenshot is below:*

[image]

I don't know why it is coming, Is it my system settings or anyother settings whether i can need to be installed?

Please suggest way to fixing this?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: try running your your cmd as admin

Comment: Pls update your angular cli

Comment: @Krishna:Am a admin

Comment: @DanielChikaka: How to update cli? This is the latest one. I tried to update using "ng update @angular/cli" . same err is returned

Comment: @KarthicG check here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli, then update the version on package.json file then do npm install

Comment: As a user of both Unix & Windows file systems, I would recommend avoiding Windows operating systems when interacting with npm/node. There are so many aspects of common Windows installations that screw up npm/yarn installs, ranging from EPERM issues with IDEs, to intrusive file-watching virus scanners.

 If you must use Windows, use something like [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) to cleanly manage node/npm/yarn, and get rid of any file-watching software like real-time virus scanners.

Comment: anyone tell clear solution for this